# Utilizar duas classes CSS em C# Razor MVC

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou querendo utilizar duas classes CSS no Razor. É possível fazer isso? Pois não estou conseguindo.

Estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ativo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @id = "ativo" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ativo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control flat" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ativo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Mas a estilização da classe "flat" não funciona. Alguém tem alguma solução?

Comment: Tem certeza que a classe não está sendo aplicada? Porque é assim mesmo que se faz, se não me falha a memória.

Comment: A forma de atribuir as classes CSS no componente está correta, poderia postar a declaração da classe `flat` por gentileza?

Comment: Lucas, você não pode esquecer de referenciar o seu arquivo de estilo. Algo do tipo `<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`